# Why do TextFields with rounded borders have a strange bottom border when placed on top of a background image?

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

Here's my TSS code:

```
"TextField": {
    font: {fontFamily: "Open Sans", fontSize: "20"},
    borderStyle: Ti.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED
},

".yourNameText": {
    top: 279,
    left: 566,
    width: 364,
    height: 45
}
```

.. and here's what it looks like:

[image: Screenshot].

Is this normal? Doesn't seem like the bottom border should be separated like that.

Comment: this is normal but . strange bottom was due to your background for view

Answer (score 1):

That shadowing is part of the border style.  No, it doesn't look good over a dark background.

Instead of `borderStyle`, you can use `borderRadius: 10` to get the same round borders. Might need to play around with the number to get it to look the way you want.

Additionally, if you want to simulate a bit of of shadow, you can use `borderColor` and `borderWidth`.

[borderRadius docs](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TextField-property-borderRadius)